# turnado websocket occur close event with code:1006

Tags: websocket, tornado

I'm a beginner using tornado and WebSocket. I'm trying to write a websocket demo with tornado to send and receive messages. However, when the client was connected to the server and was waiting to receiving messages from the server, a close event occurred with 1006 code which isbelow.

> CloseEvent {isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 1006, reason: '',
> type: 'close', …} bubbles: false cancelBubble: false cancelable: false
> code: 1006 composed: false currentTarget: WebSocket {url:
> 'ws://localhost:9998/ws', readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen:
> null, onerror: null, …} defaultPrevented: false eventPhase: 0
> isTrusted: true path: [] reason: "" returnValue: true srcElement:
> WebSocket {url: 'ws://localhost:9998/ws', readyState: 3,
> bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, …} target: WebSocket
> {url: 'ws://localhost:9998/ws', readyState: 3, bufferedAmount: 0,
> onopen: null, onerror: null, …} timeStamp: 75840 type: "close"
> wasClean: false [[Prototype]]: CloseEvent

When I'm trying to debug where caused the close event, I found that the code in the

> tornado/web.py

caused the close event.
When this code `self.request.connection.finish()` was executed ,the close event occurred. I don't know why this code can cause close event.

```
future = self.flush(include_footers=True)
self.request.connection.finish()
 self._log()
self._finished = True
self.on_finish()
self._break_cycles()
return future
```

Here is my demo code, is there anything wrong with my code that cause the close event?

The sever code:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import time


class ConnectHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler) :

    def simple_init(self):
        self.last = time.time();
        self.stop = False;

    def check_origin(self, origin) :
        return True

    def open(self) :
        self.simple_init();
        print("New client connecting")
        self.write_message('Welcome')
        print("New client connected")

    def on_close(self) :
        print("connection is closed")
        self.loop.stop();

    def on_message(self, message) :
        self.write_message('new message :' + message)


class Application(tornado.web.Application) :
    def __init__(self) :
        handlers = [
            (r'/ws', ConnectHandler)
        ]
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app = Application()
    app.listen(8889)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

The client code:

```
from websocket import create_connection


def short_lived_connection():
    ws = create_connection("ws://localhost:9998/ws");
    print("send hello server");
    ws.send("hello, server");
    print("sent");
    print("receiving...");
    result = ws.recv();
    print("Received '%s'" % result);
    ws.close();


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    short_lived_connection()
```

Comment: I have known why... The server port was 8889 and the request port was 9998...

Comment: The reason why I used 9998 port in my client script is that I used nginx for proxy, and the nginx was listening on 9998.
I tried by myself, and I found out that if didn't use nginx and changed the port to 8889, everything was OK. However, once I used nginx the close event happened...